# double tabs printed when writing single tab in c++ strings

Tags: c++, string

i'm using strings in c++ with tabs inside when the word before the tab char is less than 7 letters a normal tab is printed when it's more it prints double tabs can anyone tell me the solution ? i'm using linux and c++ 98

[image: screen shot]

the line that prints

`code`

```
bool list::search_str(LIST_TYPE &s1 , string &output){
    output = "";
    if(head ==NULL)
        return false;
    node * temp = head;
    while(temp){
        if(strstr(temp->get_data().c_str() , s1.c_str())){
            output += temp->get_data() + ":" +"\t"+"lines "+ temp->get_line_numbers() + "\n";
        }
        temp = temp->get_next();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: your question is not 100% clear.  Show what you are printing and what the output is.

Comment: this is the output
http://imgur.com/eXEf7um
this is the code just finding some words in a list 

`code`
bool list::search_str(LIST_TYPE &s1 , string &output){
    output = "";
    if(head ==NULL)
        return false;
    node * temp = head;
    while(temp){
        if(strstr(temp->get_data().c_str() , s1.c_str())){
            output += temp->get_data() + ":" +"\t"+"lines "+ temp->get_line_numbers() + "\n";
        }
        temp = temp->get_next();
    }

}

Comment: it's the same line that prints them all but different spaces each time as shown in the image

output += temp->get_data() + ":" +"\t"+"lines "+ temp->get_line_numbers() + "\n";

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect you're seeing normal tab behavior.

Comment: can't i make it all the same length ? i debugged the code it's always the same format but when printed it prints out like this

Comment: Could you add your code to the question post itself? Its unclear to read it from the comments.

Comment: use spaces with mono font if you want the same length

Comment: i added the code to the original post

Comment: It sounds like you are using tabs without actually understanding what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how tabs work: a tab in the output character string moves the output position to the next tab position. It looks like your console is set for 8-character tabs, so you have tab positions at 8, 16, 24, 32, etc. When you print something that's less than 8 characters followed by a tab, the output position moves to the 8th character position. So:

```
012345678
names:  lines 489
```

when you print something whose length is between 8 and 15 characters followed by a tab, the output position moves to the next tab position, which is at the 16th character position. So:

```
01234567012345678
program:        lines 330 404
```

If you want to put things in fixed positions you have to use character strings with embedded **spaces** rather than tabs, or you can use the manipulator `std::setw(n)` to set the width of the output field to at least `n` characters.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use tabs.  Tabs can expand to 0, 2, 3, 4, 8 spaces or space over to the next tab stop.

Using `std::ostringstream` and the `setw` I/O manipulator.

```
std::ostringstream output_stream;
//...
output_stream << temp->get_data() 
              << ":"
              << setw(32)
              << "lines "
              << temp->get_line_numbers()
              << "\n";
output = output_stream.str();
```

Also look up the `right` and `left` justification manipulators.

Answer (score 3):

This is literally the purpose of tabs. A tabspace "skips" to the next available tab column. It won't go backwards to overwrite the preceding text. Obviously if the preceding text runs over tabs 1 and 2, the next available tab is 3.

Don't use tabs if you don't want their behaviour, or if you don't understand what they do. Use fixed-space padding based on the expected width of your text columns, perhaps. For that, you'll have to precalculate what that width is.

But just randomly interjecting your output with `\t` characters don't magically re-arrange the entire output before and after into an aligned tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but if you want a fixed number of spaces to be output (1 tab is 4 spaces), then you can just do:

```
 output += temp->get_data() + ":" + "    " +"lines "+ temp->get_line_numbers() + "\n";
```

What you're experiencing is probably standard C++ behaviour. If you want to learn more about it, read the C++11, C++14, ISO standard.